# ruby and regex grouping

Tags: ruby, regex

Here is the code

```
string = "Looking for the ^[cows]"
footnote = string[/\^\[(.*?)\]/]
```

I was hoping that `footnote` would equal `cows`

What I get is `footnote` equals `^[cows]`

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: footnote is equal to `^[cows]`, because that's what you are explicitly asking for in the pattern `\^\[(.*?)\]`. The `cows` substring resides in the especial variable `$1`  (group one). Be aware that string[regexp] will return the match of the entire pattern, not the groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify which capture group you want with a [second argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) to `[]`:

```
string = "Looking for the ^[cows]"
footnote = string[/\^\[(.*?)\]/, 1]
# footnote == "cows"
```

Comment: .match() might be a better solution in some cases, but this works best for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture subgroups, you can use `Regexp#match`:

```
r = /\^\[(.*?)\]/
r.match(string) # => #<MatchData "^[cows]" 1:"cows">
r.match(string)[0] # => "^[cows]"
r.match(string)[1] # => "cows"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`String` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), the `#[]` method takes a second parameter, an integer, which determines the matching group returned:

```
a = "hello there"

a[/[aeiou](.)\1/]      #=> "ell"
a[/[aeiou](.)\1/, 0]   #=> "ell"
a[/[aeiou](.)\1/, 1]   #=> "l"
a[/[aeiou](.)\1/, 2]   #=> nil
```

You should use `footnote = string[/\^\[(.*?)\]/, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using a capture group, and then retrieving it's contents, is to match only what you want. Here are three ways of doing that.

**#1 Use a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead**

```
string[/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/]
  #=> "cows"
```

**#2 Use match but forget (`\K`) and a positive lookahead**

```
string[/\[\K.*?(?=\])/]
  #=> "cows"
```

**#3 Use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)**

```
string.gsub(/.*?\[|\].*/,'')
  #=> "cows"
```